# I'm doing a Caesar Cipher coding challenge, and I'm not sure why it's not outputting correctly

Tags: python, text, caesar-cipher

Ok full disclosure I'm using brute force way first (I know it can be done more efficiently in other ways like using modulus and one for loop). I wanted to see how it can be done with brute force and not sure why it's not outputting what I need. I've gone over the logic over and over again and can't seem to find the issue. Please explain! Thank you!

The message is supposed to have an offset of 10.
[My code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjwt8.png)

The output: hei dhebe! dhic ic ah ehagzfe if a caecab cizheb. gebe iie abfe di decide id? i hize ci! cehd ge a geccage bace gidh dhe cage iffced!

What I should get: hey there! this is an example of a caesar cipher. were you able to decode it? i hope so! send me a message back with the same offset!

Comment: Why did you link to a picture of your code instead of just pasting the code directly into the question?

Comment: To be honest I was struggling to get it to format properly when I pasted it haha... It kept trying to put all the code on one line even after manually indenting everything

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to post code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
message = "xuo jxuhu! jxyi yi qd unqcfbu ev q squiqh syfxuh. muhu oek qrbu je tusetu yj? y xefu ie! iudt cu q cuiiqwu rqsa myjx jxu iqcu evviuj!"
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
message = list(message)
alphabet = list(alphabet)

temp = 0
for item in range(len(message)):
    for a in range(len(alphabet)):
        if message[item] == alphabet[a]:
            if a + 10 <= 25:
                message[item] = alphabet[a + 10]
            else:
                temp = 10 - (26 - a)    #26 instead of 25 here
                message[item] = alphabet[temp]
            break                       # need to break the for loop otherwise it will keep comparing with alphabet after it changed

message = "".join(message)
print(message)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the guidance. I was able to get it fixed by adding the "break" statement. However, it is supposed to be 25, not 26 due to the indices starting at 0 in a list. But thank you for the hint with the break statement! Appreciate it!